# Splitting TypeReps of applied constructors

Tags: haskell, introspection

I'm trying to use [`Data.Typeable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html) to inspect the component types of a function type. At first, [`typeRepArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html#v%3atypeRepArgs) looks perfect, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
Prelude Data.Typeable> typeRepArgs (typeOf2 (id :: Integer -> Integer))
[]
Prelude Data.Typeable> length $ typeRepArgs (typeOf2 (id :: Integer -> Integer))
0
```

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how this is supposed to work? Clearly the `(->)` constructor is being applied to two arguments, so why can't I see them? If I try prodding the function type in the way of `dynApply` from `Data.Dynamic`, I get a similarly puzzling result:

```
Prelude Data.Typeable> funResultTy (typeOf2 (id :: Integer -> Integer)) (typeOf (0 :: Integer))
Nothing
```

I'm really quite stumped.

If it helps, I'm using GHC 7.0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the nullary version `typeOf`

```
Prelude Data.Typeable> typeRepArgs $ typeOf (undefined :: Int -> Int)
[Int,Int]
```

However, this might not do what you'd expect. It gives the type arguments of the type constructor `(->)`, so for a function with more than one argument you get something like this.

```
Prelude Data.Typeable> typeRepArgs $ typeOf (undefined :: Int -> Int -> Int)
[Int,Int -> Int]
```

If you want to get the argument types of a curried function, you'll have to recursively deconstruct the function type.

Comment: D'oh. This is exactly what I expected `typeOf2` to do. I used it right off the bat, expecting it to be the right choice for a `* -> * -> *` constructor, but forgot that the value I'm inspecting is actually of kind `*`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Prelude Data.Typeable> typeRepArgs (typeOf (id :: Integer -> Integer))
[Integer,Integer]
```

Comment: You'd think I would have tried that first, rather than getting clever with the higher-kinded classes... thanks.